# Getting message "Printing completed" but nothing is actually printed... randomly

Tags: printing, cups

I have a shared over the network printer connected via USB to a Windows box.

I am printing from my Linux laptop with Pop_OS 19.10 but sometimes it will say that the print Job is complete but actually hasn't printed anything.

I've already saw a loo of people with the same problem however, in my case it happens randomly.

Today I've received an email with two pdfs. The first pdf I've tried to print didn't print, the second one printed without any problem. I've tried to print again the first pdf, just to check, but I had the same problem again.

This has been happening to me for the couple of weeks or so. Up to that time I had no problem printing from my linux laptop.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Pop!_OS 19.10"
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="19.10"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
HOME_URL="https://system76.com/pop"
SUPPORT_URL="http://support.system76.com"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://system76.com/privacy"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan
LOGO=distributor-logo-pop-os


cups:
  Installed: 2.2.12-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.2.12-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.12-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

smbclient:
  Installed: 2:4.10.7+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4
  Candidate: 2:4.10.7+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4
  Version table:
 *** 2:4.10.7+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:4.10.7+dfsg-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
```

EDIT:

I could print the file from CLI using `lp file.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me that by mistake I configured a printer (with similar name!) that just shipped to null. Doing `lpr -Pprinter something` got "normal printing" as you say. Insidious if the wrong name gets configured e.g. into LibreOffice...

It might be a filter malfunction (e.g. the translation of *only* PDF breaks, and nothing is printed), borked files you send to print (depending on format, try to look at them with a viewer, any corruption should be aparent), wrong printer driver.

See if upgrading fixes this. Check the CUPS page `http://localhost:631`, see what it reports for the failed print jobs. Check the CUPS manuals, there are ways of digging in and debugging this, but not very simple ones.

Search the web for your distribution and printer. Perhaps a known bug?

Comment: Everything was ok. I've just tried printing the file from the command line and it worked but printing from the GUI still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to the Windows machine and see if it will print directly. If it doesn't print there is a document corruption issue. 
If it does print then probably your missing a font in the Linux System. 
I had a similar issue and had to install additional fonts in the Linux system to allow the document to print on the windows print server.

Comment: printing the file from the windows box what I had to do in order to print the file. I would understan the issue with the fonts if they were files with different origin. But we are talking about two attached pdf files that were generated in the same computer and sent to me in one email.